# How can I echo a string that ends with a digit?

Tags: windows, cmd, echo, io-redirection

In Windows command line, I'm trying to write the following string to a file:

```
cloud 9
```

First, I try `echo cloud 9> file.txt`. This just prints to the console, not the file, presumably due to the undefined nature of `9>`.

Next I try `echo cloud 9 > file.txt`. This yields a file that contains the desired text `cloud 9`, but with a trailing space at the end of the line.

I tried a bunch of other variations:

`echo cloud 91> file.txt` yields `cloud 91`.

`echo cloud 9 1> file.txt` yields `cloud 9` with a trailing space.

`echo "cloud 9"> file.txt` yields `"cloud 9"` with undesired quotation marks.

**Is there any way to echo exactly `cloud 9`, with no trailing spaces, to a file?**

Comment: Does it work if you do `echo %CL%>foo` and `set CL=...` before ? Perhaps the caret can help too

Comment: `(Echo cloud 9)>"file.txt"` or `>"file.txt" Echo cloud 9` are my suggestions! Of the two, my preference is for the former, but remember that you'll need to escape any closing parenthesis in your 'string to echo', to prevent it prematurely closing the block, _i.e. `^)`_.

Comment: @Marged, your suggestion cannot work unfortunately, because the `%`-expansion happens even before recognition of redirection operators; you'd need to do `call echo %^CL%>file.txt`, or `echo !CL!>file.txt` (with [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled), or `for %I in ("cloud 9") do @echo %~I>file.txt`, all to gain another later layer of expansion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I/O redirections don't have to be at the end of the command. Try

```
echo>file.txt cloud 9
```

or

```
>file.txt echo cloud 9
```

Other possible alternatives:

escape the `9`:

```
echo cloud ^9>file.txt
```

surround the text with parentheses: (note that any interior closing-parentheses will need to be escaped)

```
(echo cloud 9) > file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

My preferred method is to put the [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) portion in front of the command:

```cmd
> "file.txt" echo cloud 9
```

Anyway, you may hide the echoed text with the number in a variable. Though take into account that immediate variable expansion, or percent-(`%`-)expansion, happens even before redirection expressions are recognised, so `set "CL=cloud 9"` and then `echo %CL%> "file.txt"` is not going to work. But there are some other ways:

1. Use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (enable it by running the command prompt with `cmd /V`):

   ```cmd
   set "CL=cloud 9"
   echo !CL!> "file.txt"
   ```

   Or in a single line:

   ```cmd
   set "CL=cloud 9" & echo !CL!> "file.txt"
   ```

   This may cause trouble when the text string contains `!` and/or `^`.
2. Use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) later, but have it disabled initially:

   ```cmd
   set "CL=cloud 9"
   cmd /V /C echo !CL!> "file.txt"
   ```

   Or in a single line:

   ```cmd
   set "CL=cloud 9" & cmd /V /C echo !CL!> "file.txt"
   ```

   This is expected to work even with `!` and/or `^` occurring in the text string.

   If delayed expansion is already enabled from the beginning, `cmd /V /C echo !CL!` needs to be replaced by `cmd /V /C echo ^^!CL^^!`.
3. Use [`call`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to introduce another delayed layer of variable expansion:

   ```cmd
   set "CL=cloud 9"
   call echo %^CL%> "file.txt"
   ```

   Or again in one line:

   ```cmd
   set "CL=cloud 9" & call echo %^CL%> "file.txt"
   ```

   This may cause trouble when the text string contains `^`. And actually this relies on the fact that there is no variable `^CL` defined.
4. Use a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop to achieve later expansion of the meta-variable:

   ```cmd
   for %I in ("cloud 9") do @echo %~I> "file.txt"
   ```

   This may cause trouble when the text string contains `*`, `?` or `<`, `>`.

---

By the way, you may want to replace `echo Text` by `echo(Text`, because this is the only safe way of echoing an arbitrary text when `Text` is unknown and may even be blank, according to [this post on DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=774#p4554).